# How to access authentication by Strava API using Python?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, access-token, strava

I am starting a small python script (not an application) that can upload my *.fit activity files on Strava whenever they are created in a desired folder.

The main steps I plan to do are:

```
1. monitor *.fit file system modifications
2. access authentication to Strava to enable my program to upload files
   (This tool will be personal use only, thus I expect no need to authenticate every time uploading)
3. upload the file to my Strava account
4. automatically doing this fixed routine with the help of Windows Task Scheduler
   (For example, there will be 4-5 new riding activities generated in my computer folder, I expect this tool can automatically upload all of them once a week so that I do not need to manually complete the task.)
```

For **step2**,  I really have no ideas how to implement even though reading through [Strava Authentication Documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/#requestingaccess) and several source codes other peoples have developed (e.g. [toravir's "rk2s (RunKeeper 2 Strava)" project on GitHub](https://github.com/toravir/rk2s)). I grabbed that some of the python modules like  **stravalib, swagger_client, request, json**, etc. as well as concepts like **OAuth2** may be related to **step2** but I still can not put everything together...

Can any experienced give me some advice for the implementations of **step2**? or any related readings will be perfect!

Advice for other parts of this project will also be very welcomed and appreciated.

I thank you very much in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code example on how you can access the Strava API, check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/oddeirikigland/f7cd0a28d8f09f64893e1fb64b796285) or use the code below:

```py
import time
import pickle
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from stravalib.client import Client

CLIENT_ID = 'GET FROM STRAVA API SITE'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'GET FROM STRAVA API SITE'
REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/authorized'

app = FastAPI()
client = Client()

def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:  # Overwrites any existing file.
        pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def load_object(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input:
        loaded_object = pickle.load(input)
        return loaded_object


def check_token():
    if time.time() > client.token_expires_at:
        refresh_response = client.refresh_access_token(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, refresh_token=client.refresh_token)
        access_token = refresh_response['access_token']
        refresh_token = refresh_response['refresh_token']
        expires_at = refresh_response['expires_at']
        client.access_token = access_token
        client.refresh_token = refresh_token
        client.token_expires_at = expires_at

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    authorize_url = client.authorization_url(client_id=CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL)
    return RedirectResponse(authorize_url)


@app.get("/authorized/")
def get_code(state=None, code=None, scope=None):
    token_response = client.exchange_code_for_token(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, code=code)
    access_token = token_response['access_token']
    refresh_token = token_response['refresh_token']
    expires_at = token_response['expires_at']
    client.access_token = access_token
    client.refresh_token = refresh_token
    client.token_expires_at = expires_at
    save_object(client, 'client.pkl')
    return {"state": state, "code": code, "scope": scope}

try:
    client = load_object('client.pkl')
    check_token()
    athlete = client.get_athlete()
    print("For {id}, I now have an access token {token}".format(id=athlete.id, token=client.access_token))

    # To upload an activity
    # client.upload_activity(activity_file, data_type, name=None, description=None, activity_type=None, private=None, external_id=None)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No access token stored yet, visit http://localhost:8000/ to get it")
    print("After visiting that url, a pickle file is stored, run this file again to upload your activity")
```

Download that file, install the requirements, and run it (assuming the filename is main):

```sh
pip install stravalib
pip install fastapi
pip install uvicorn
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to authenticate using OAuth in order to upload your activity, which pretty much requires you to have a web server setup that Strava can post back to after you "Authorize". I just set the authentication piece up using Rails & Heroku.

This link has a pretty good flowchart of what needs to happen.
https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like if you go to [API Settings](https://www.strava.com/settings/api) you can get your access token and refresh token there. I would also check out the [Python Strava Library](https://github.com/hozn/stravalib#authentication) but it looks like you could do something like:

```py
from stravalib.client import Client
access_token = 'your_access_token_from_your_api_application_settings_page'
refresh_token = 'your_refresh_token_from_your_api_application_settings_page' 

client = Client()

athlete = client.get_athlete()
```

You may need to dig in a little more to that library to figure out the upload piece.